# delete one or more selected data from table in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a table in which data is entered by the user by the help of forms. I have used JSON server to store data. I am facing problem in deleting selected data from table. How to delete one or more selected data by user from the table.

I have created a table in which data is entered by the user by the help of forms. I have used JSON server to store data. I am facing problem in deleting selected data from table. How to delete one or more selected data by user from the table.

*app.component.html*

```
<table style="color:blue; border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Issue Description
      </th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Severity
      </th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
        status
      </th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Created date
      </th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Resolved date
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray">
      <td>{{ field.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.severity }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.createddate }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.resolveddate }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
<br>
<form style="color:brown">
  Enter Issue Description:
  <input
    class="form-control"
    type="text"
    id="newAttributeName"
    [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.description"
    name="description"
  />
  <br><br>
  Severity
  <select name="severity" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.severity">
    <option value="minor">minor</option>
    <option value="major">major</option>
    <option value="critical">critical</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  status
  <select name="status" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.status">
    <option value="open">open</option>
    <option value="In Progress">inprogress</option>
    <option value="closed">closed</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Created date:
  <input
    type="date"
    class="form-control"
    id="newAttributecreateddate"
    [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.createddate"
    name="createddate"
  >
  <br><br>
  Resolved date:
  <input
    type="date"
    class="form-control"
    id="newAttributeresolvedate"
    [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.resolveddate"
    name="resolveddate"
  >
  <br><br>
  <button
    [disabled]="!newAttribute.description || !newAttribute.severity || !newAttribute.status || !newAttribute.createddate
    || !newAttribute.resolveddate" 
    class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="addFieldValue($event)"
  >
    Add
  </button>
</form>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  recenltyAddedProduct: any;
  fieldArray: Array<any>;
  newAttribute: any;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.title = "assignment3";
    this.fieldArray = [];
    this.newAttribute = {};
  }

  fetchData = function() {
    this.httpClient
      .get("http://localhost:3000/products").subscribe(res => {
        this.fieldArray = res;
      });
  };

  addFieldValue() {
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
    this.recenltyAddedProduct = this.newAttribute;
    this.newAttribute = {};
    this.httpClient
      .post("http://localhost:3000/products", this.recenltyAddedProduct)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("added");
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you mean delete it from the local `fieldArray` array, then you just splice it out of the array, and the template will update automatically, thanks to data binding. If you mean how to delete it from the server, thats an **entirely** different process, one in which you need to send the object to delete to the server and handle it there...

Comment: you need to send request to remove data on server side and await updated data list. Also using `http://localhost:3000/products` will fail after building production version of your application.

Answer (score 0):

So your table is rendering the fieldArray which is an Array of values. If you remove the correct item from the array the table will be re-rendered and display the correct data you need. Thats the main concept of data binding and change detection in Angular :-)

You can use `fieldArray.splice(index,1)` to remove the item you (or the user) selected